# Is it possible to initialize a const struct without using a function?

Tags: c

I have a fairly simple const struct in some C code that simply holds a few pointers and would like to initialize it statically if possible. Can I and, if so, how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can, if the pointers point to global objects:

```
// In global scope
int x, y;
const struct {int *px, *py; } s = {&x, &y};
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const struct mytype  foo = {&var1, &var2};
```

Answer (score 2):

A const struct can *only* be initialized statically.

Answer (score 0):

But if there is some `struct` as following:

```
struct Foo
{
    const int a;
    int b;
};
```

and we want to dynamically create the pointer to the `struct` using `malloc`, so can we play the trick:

```
struct Foo foo = { 10, 20 };
char *ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(struct Foo));
memcpy(ptr, &foo, sizeof(foo));
struct Foo *pfoo = (struct Foo*)ptr;
```

this is very useful especially when some function needs to return pointer to `struct Foo`